# How did the author take this derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations

*From Taylor's Classical Mechanics, pg. 220:*

> Given: $f(y+\eta (x)\alpha,y'+\eta (x) '\alpha,x)$
>
> Derivative: $\frac{\partial f(y+\eta (x)\alpha,y'+\eta (x) '\alpha,x)}{\partial \alpha}=\eta \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\eta' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$

I guess I can see how the derivative is a summation of 2 terms - it's because there are 2 terms in the argument for the function that depend on $\alpha$. However, I don't see where the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$ come from. I would have just said that the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ is $\eta + \eta '$.

---

Update: My main question is just this now: why does the author take the derivative of $f$ w.r.t $y$? He wanted to find the derivative with respect to a parameter that introduced, which is $\alpha$.

Comment: How can the derivative of a general function be independent of that function? It seems rather odd. Would you say that the derivative of f(a x) with respect to a is x? It breaks the chain rule

Comment: Update: $\frac{d}{dx}f(x+y)=\frac{d}{dy}f(x+y)$ so this is valid. The reason to do this is to clarify which term the author is taking a derivative with respect to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The letters seem to be confusing you, and this is understandable.

Perhaps if we instead write $\eta f^{(1,0,0)}+\eta'f^{(0,1,0)}$ it would make more sense? Here I am using the tuple to indicate which argument to differentiate with respect to. For instance, if begin with the function $f(u,v,w)=uv^2w^3$ then we have

$$\begin{array}{l} f^{(1,0,0)}(u,v,w)=(1u^0)v^2w^3=v^2w^3, \\  f^{(0,1,0)}(u,v,w)=u(2v^1)w^3=2uvw^3, \\ f^{(0,0,1)}(u,v,w)=uv^2(3w^2)=3uv^2w^2. \end{array}$$

From this we could compute e.g. the derivative of $f(a(x),b(x),c(x))$ with respect to $x$:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(a(x),b(x),c(x))=a'(x)f^{(1,0,0)}+b'(x)f^{(0,1,0)}+c'(x)f^{(0,0,1)} $$

$$=a'(x)\cdot\big(b(x)^2c(x)^3\big)+b'(x)\cdot\big(2a(x)b(x)c(x)^3\big)+c'(x)\cdot\big(3a(x)b(x)^2c(x)^2\big). $$

If we normally write $f$ as $f(y,y',x)$ for example, then we might refer to $f^{(1,0,0)}$ and $f^{(0,1,0)}$ using the notation $\partial f/\partial y$ and $\partial f/\partial y'$ respectively, even if we're evaluating at an ordered tuple that looks a bit different from $(y,y',x)$, such as $(y+\eta(x)\alpha,y'+\eta'(x)\alpha,x)$.

Comment: Another notation sometimes used is $\mathrm D_1f$ for derivative with respect to the first argument, $\mathrm D_2f$ for derivative w.r.t. the second argument, and so on.

Comment: What you've written makes sense, but the author is trying to take the derivative w.r.t the parameter $\alpha$, not $x$. How can he do this and yet still end up taking the derivative w.r.t $y$ in his answer??

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Did you not read my answer? Using the tuple notation, it would be written as the following: $$\frac{df}{d\alpha}=\frac{\partial (y+\eta(x)\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}f^{(1,0,0)}+\frac{\partial(y'+\eta'(x)\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}f^{(0,1,0)}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial\alpha}f^{(0,0,1)} $$ If you read the last part of my answer, it addresses how to interpret the notation. When the author writes $\partial f/\partial y$ and $\partial f/\partial y'$, they mean what I write as $f^{(1,0,0)}$ and $f^{(0,1,0)}$.

Comment: @arctictern I did, but I'm still confused.

Comment: I don't know what it is you're confused about unfortunately.

Comment: Why is $y$ being used to denote both the first variable that $f$ depends on AND a function that "$y$" depends on. (i.e $f^{(1,0,0)} = y + \eta(x)\alpha$ ). Seems pretty ambiguous

Comment: @DavidFeng Instead of thinking of the letter $y$ itself having a meaning within the notation $\partial/\partial y$, maybe think of $\partial/\partial y$ as a whole having the meaning "take the derivative of $f$ with respect to whichever argument we called $y$ originally." I didn't invent the practice, I'm not fond of it either. Also, no idea where you're getting the idea $f^{(1,0,0)}=y+\eta(x)\alpha$ from. We don't know what $f^{(1,0,0)}$ is because we don't know what $f$ is.

Comment: @arctictern Sorry I misinterpreted the notation you wrote, what I meant by $f^(1,0,0)$ is the first argument of $f$. I agree with you, that practise is very misleading.. especially since it wasn't stated in the question which variables corresponded to which arguements (unless it is also convention that $f=f(y,y',x)$ in that order? Assuming we are talking about 1st order ODEs in this context)

Comment: @DavidFeng OP may not have stated it, but I'm sure the book did. They're doing calculus of variations on the functional $f(y,y',x)$ of $y$ by perturbing $y$ by $\alpha\eta(x)$ (where $\eta(x)$ is a function describing the "shape" of the perturbation and $\alpha$ the "size," roughly) which means they need to see how fast $$f(y+\alpha\eta(x),y'+\alpha\eta'(x),x)\to f(y,y',x)$$ as the parameter $\alpha\to0$. This is how we derive the Euler-Lagrange equations. (Different sources have different orders to $y,y',x$ but the perturbed function should have them appear in the same order as the original.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the chain rule!  $y + \eta(x)\alpha$ for example is one of the arguments of the function, not a function itself!!

Hence what you have to do is to differentate the function first and then the functions inside it!

Comment: Why does the author differentiate with respect to $y$? Why not w.r.t $x$ or $\alpha$?