# How this chain rule works?

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I am struggling to understand how this derivative works (differentiating a functional from calculus of variations):

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}f(y(x)+\alpha\eta(x), y'(x)+\alpha\eta'(x), x)=\eta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\eta'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$$

I am not sure why we need to add two terms in the final result.

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule?

Comment: @zkutch I am familiar with the basic $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$ chain rule but I am not sure how it applies here.

Comment: You need here chain rule for multiple variables. For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case. Could you try to do as it says?

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that somebody else already asked this exact same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2050543/817718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume, that we have function $t=f(x,y,z)=f(x(u,v, \alpha), y(u,v, \alpha),z(u,v, \alpha))$, then chain rule with respect, for example, $\alpha$ will be

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \alpha}$$
In your case it's enough to see that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \alpha} = \eta$, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} = \eta'$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \alpha} = 0$.

To make things looking exactly as in question, let's consider $t=f(y,y',y'')=f(y(u,v, \alpha), y'(u,v, \alpha),y''(u,v, \alpha))$
Then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\frac{\partial y'}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y''}\frac{\partial y''}{\partial \alpha}$$
and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} = \eta$, $\frac{\partial y'}{\partial \alpha} = \eta'$ and $\frac{\partial y''}{\partial \alpha} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you but how do you find out $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$? I am not sure how $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial (y+\alpha\eta)}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Comment: In fact $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is a formal notation for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the first variable. In your question you denote it as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Also is possible to write $f'_1$.

Comment: Added a part where the symbols match yours.

Comment: Ah I see $y(u,v,\alpha)=u(x)+\alpha v(x)$ right?

Comment: In principle right, only you used slightly different letters. What is a little confusing in your question is that you used the letter $y$ both as a designation for the first variable for $f$, and also as a function $y(x)$ in an internal variable.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. That came from my professor's notes, unfortunately.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.